# How to do a raised initial in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image]

Please, how do you do a raised initial like the example in InDesign?

Thank you,

Elizabeth Hart

Comment: Did one of these answers solve  your problem Elizabeth? Please consider marking one of the answers as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by creating a Paragraph Style with a nested Character Style.

1. Create a paragraph style with a Drop Cap of 1 line and 1 character.
2. Click the New Nested Style button
3. Set character style to the font size/color, etc. you would like the initial cap to be and name it something memorable (I named it Raised Cap).

When this is done you can go in and customize the styles more to refine the settings. Hope this helps.
[image: Paragraph Style Dialog Box]

[image: Raised Initial Cap example]

Answer (score 2):

It's not actually considered a raised initial. It's really just a larger font size. As you increase a font's size, it gets larger upward.

So if your body copy is 10pt font, you would just make the first letter like 80pt font to achieve something like what you've shown.

Comment: What about a raised cap as opposed to a drop cap? Is there such thing as a raised cap?

Comment: @ElizabethHart: um, you mean as a *specific function*? There is no need for that, because it already works the way Peacockerie describes - other than a Drop Cap, which needs far more manual tinkering.

Comment: A drop cap is a letter with a dropped baseline. A raised cap is a dropped cap with a negative drop (a raised baseline). Much in the same way that there is technically no such thing as deceleration in physics. The automatic functions like in ispaany's answer are there more for auto-styling (a particular convenience afforded by computing). The name of the feature is immaterial.